# golang: why there's no deadlock in this code?

Tags: go, channel

golang: Why there's no deadlock in this code?

Please go through this following code:

```
package main
  

import (
    "fmt"
    "time"
)


func f1(done chan bool) {
    done <- true
    fmt.Printf("this's f1() goroutine\n")
}

func f2(done chan bool) {
    val := <-done
    fmt.Printf("this's f2() goroutine. val: %t\n", val)
}


func main() {
    done1 := make(chan bool)
    done2 := make(chan bool)

    go f1(done1)
    go f2(done2)
    
    fmt.Printf("main() go-routine is waiting to see deadlock.\n")
    time.Sleep(5 * time.Second)
}
```

As one can see, go-routine f1() is sending a value onto the channel. And go-routine f2() is receiving a value from a channel.
However, there's no go-routine receiving from the channel which is being sent onto by go-routine f1().
Similarly, there's no go-routine sending onto the channel which is being received from by go-routine f2().

Comment: Simply because when the 5 seconds sleep passes, the `main` goroutine can proceed. In a deadlock, none of the goroutines can proceed, _ever_.

Comment: @mh-cbon: there are two different channels in the code

Comment: You don't "wait" for a deadlock, it has nothing to do with how *long* the goroutines are inactive for

Comment: @HymnsForDisco
Absolutely. The wait here was deliberate and I just wanted to make a point as no matter how long the main go-routine waited, it still wasn't the deadlock situation.

Comment: @EliBendersky
Also, 2 different channels wouldn't make any difference, IMO.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As @icza's comment correctly states, a deadlock happens when *all* goroutines are stuck and can't make progress. In your case `f1` and `f2` are stuck, but the main goroutine is not - so this isn't a deadlock.

However, it *is* a goroutine leak! Goroutine leaks happen when some code finishes its logical existence but leaves goroutines running (unterminated). I've found tools like `github.com/fortytw2/leaktest` useful for detecting goroutine leaks, and it would detect the issue in your code - give it a try.

Here's a modified code sample:

```
import (
    "testing"
    "time"

    "github.com/fortytw2/leaktest"
)


func f1(done chan bool) {
    done <- true
    fmt.Printf("this's f1() goroutine\n")
}

func f2(done chan bool) {
    val := <-done
    fmt.Printf("this's f2() goroutine. val: %t\n", val)
}

func TestTwoGoroutines(t *testing.T) {
    defer leaktest.CheckTimeout(t, time.Second)()

    done1 := make(chan bool)
    done2 := make(chan bool)

    go f1(done1)
    go f2(done2)
}
```

When you run this test, you'll see something like:

```
--- FAIL: TestTwoGoroutines (1.03s)
    leaktest.go:132: leaktest: timed out checking goroutines
    leaktest.go:150: leaktest: leaked goroutine: goroutine 7 [chan send]:
        leaktest-samples.f1(0xc000016420)
            leaktest-samples/leaktest1_test.go:45 +0x37
        created by leaktest-samples.TestTwoGoroutines
            leaktest-samples/leaktest1_test.go:60 +0xd1
    leaktest.go:150: leaktest: leaked goroutine: goroutine 8 [chan receive]:
        leaktest-samples.f2(0xc000016480)
            leaktest-samples/leaktest1_test.go:50 +0x3e
        created by leaktest-samples.TestTwoGoroutines
            leaktest-samples/leaktest1_test.go:61 +0xf3
```

Answer (score 0):

As @icza said, the main goroutine can continue and ultimately terminate.

If you remove the `go` keyword from either of the two function calls (make them occur on the main goroutine) then the application has a deadlock. See this go playground (it highlights the deadlock for you) https://play.golang.org/p/r9qo2sc9LQA

Comment: But there's one more thing to it.

Answer (score 0):

There's one more thing to it.

```
func f1(done chan bool) {
    fmt.Printf("f1()\n")
}

func main() {
    done := make(chan bool)
    go f1(done)
    done <- true
}
```

Here, the caller go-routine clearly gets stuck since there's no go-routine in existence that's receiving from the channel.

Here, not that all the go-routines are blocked (f1() slips through), but there's still a dead-lock. The reason being, there has to be at least 1 go routine that should be receiving from the channel.
But this clearly contradicts the above comment and not all go-routines are blocked here.

Comment: f1 runs then terminates. Therefore there is only one goroutine left, the main goroutine - which is blocked (waiting for a receive), therefore the program is in deadlock.